# Min number 'x' to be multiplied to 'a' to make it divisible by 'b'

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My question is this. Given any two arbitrary positive integers **a** and **b** ∈ z , what is the minimum value of **x** such that:

`b | (a * x)` Find MINIMUM positive x such that product of a and x is divisible by b.

or Find minimum positive x such that:

**ax ≡ 0 mod(b)**

How do I solve this general equation to find min x for any arbitrary integers a & b?

For example:

**ex1**  a = 5, b = 14.  Then x = 14 because  14 | 5x   and 14 | 5 * 14

**ex2**  a = 14, b = 4,  Then x = 2 because 4 | 14 * x and  4 | 14 * 2

Right now I'm using brute force program for solving this:

```
int x, limit = b;

// We know that Limit is b since b | a * b, we want to find x <= b

for(x = 1 ; x <= limit ; x++) {

    if((a * x) % b == 0)) {

        // exit the loop. solution found
        break;

    }
}

// prints minimum x and the value a*x for which b | a*x
print(x ,  a * x);
```

Please recommend an efficient mathematical solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the greatest common divisor of $a,b$.  Then evaluate $x=\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$  You can prove this by considering the prime factorization of $b$.  Then the equation reduces to $b | (a * \frac b{\gcd(a,b)})$ which is always true.

Comment: Your answer seems to be right but could you rewrite the variables in your answer please. I am interested in Finding 'X', not 'a'. We might find it confusing... Find 'x' such that 'b' divides product of 'a' and 'x'

Comment: I suggest, oath, that you take it as an exercise to correct the error in Ross' formula. Then you will know that you truly understand the solution.

Comment: I have made edits to this answer. The edit will make it easier for others to understand. I'll have to see if the edit gets accepted. For now, I'll mark @Ross's answer as accepted. Thank you for your help :)